# Inject dependency via constructor or at class method level?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection

Need one design suggestion.
Please see the class below.
Class has just one method
Class has constructor that takes userName and passWord as parameters.
Question is - Whats the difference if 
-- If i remove the username and pwd from constructor
-- And send (userName, password) to the AuthoriseUser method

All this in the background of injecting dependency

```
 public class UserNameAuthorisationService : IUserNameAuthorisationService
{
    private readonly string _userName;
    private readonly string _password;
    private readonly IUserNameAuthorisationRepository _usernameAuthRepository;

    public UserNameAuthorisationService(string UserName, string Password, IUserNameAuthorisationRepository UsernameAuthRepository)
    {
        _userName = UserName;
        _password = Password;
        _usernameAuthRepository = UsernameAuthRepository;
    }

    public IUser AuthoriseUser()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing initial parameters in constructor is good for non-mutable objects, as if you dont provide setter method it is "impossible" (if not considering any reflection tricks) to change them.

If you plan to not allow this values to change via your API, this is the only way to achieve this requirement. Otherwise you can implement setters. Even implementing setters you may think that this object cant exist (is pointless to exist) without a username and a password, in this  case I would keep both setters and constructor initiation.

As I see this object has no meaning to exist without password/username/repository, so I would keep their initialization at constructor.

I would move username and password params to `AuthoriseUser` method if `UserNameAuthorisationService` were supposed to act as a component, and have for example, one unique application instance (your DI container should manage this). In this scenario I would inject this object in client objects via DI.

The key point is to keep your object at a consistent state all the times, not using init() nor populate() methods. So as @Maxim pointed out, alway fully initialize your objects and keep them always at a usable state, in a way you dont have to throw an exception if `AuthoriseUser()` is called without mandatory parameters that were supposed to be pre-populated.

Comment: Thanks Renato - I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea to define arguments constructor is to initiate class with *start* parameters.
If you don't want to change user/password in the future its good practice to use   arguments constructor.

On other hand if you going to change user/password - use `set` methods and no-arguments constructor.

BTW, creating a class that is not fully initialized  called *two-step construction* is an anti-pattern

Answer (score 2):

Ok, in general, I try to follow this pattern:
If I have a chance, I will use the **Constructor Injection** for the external dependencies

1. I will use **Constructor Injection** where possible
2. I will use the **Property Injection** in case there is no possibility to incorporate the **Constructor Injection** and I have a good **Default** value
3. The **Method Injection** has certain advantages in a specific scenarios when the dependency can vary with each method call (look here for
   more details: http://manning.com/seemann/DIi.NET_sample_ch04.pdf)

In your case, I would do the following:

1. Leave the repository injection in the constructor
2. Move user name and password to the method context as most likely they will not be provided by the DI container but they are context-specific. I would not consider these parameters as dependencies but as value objects or so.

Having the constructor injection in place is the best possible approach with the DI in general. One of the biggest advantages is that you can easily see if your class violates SOLID principles and you see how many dependencies you have in a single place